# Not able to retrive a single document through a Stream using Riverpod & Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'm building an app where I would like to retrieve a user profile document from Firebase and populate it into a user profile screen.

I have written a "UserProfileRepository" class where there is a function that returns a stream for the user profile. I'm calling this function through a Provider so I can access the stream on the user profile screen using a StreamBuilder object.

```
class UserProfileRepository {
  UserProfileRepository(this._fireStore);
  final FirebaseFirestore _fireStore;

  static String userProfilesPath = 'user-profiles';
  static String userProfilePath(String uid) => 'user-profiles/$uid';

  // read
  Stream<UserProfile> watchUser(String uid) => _fireStore
      .doc('user-profiles/$uid')
      .withConverter<UserProfile>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
              UserProfile.fromMap(snapshot.data()!, uid),
          toFirestore: (user, _) => user.toMap())
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.data()!);
}

final userProfileRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return UserProfileRepository(FirebaseFirestore.instance);
});

final userProfileStreamProvider = StreamProvider<UserProfile>((ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    throw AssertionError('User can\'t be null.');
  }
  final repository = ref.watch(userProfileRepositoryProvider);
  return repository.watchUser(user.uid);
});
```

Here is how I'm calling the provider in the user profile screen:

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final userProfile = ref.watch(userProfileStreamProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: userProfile.when(
        loading: () => const Text('Widget to show when loading'),
        error: (error, stackTrace) => const Text('Widget to show on error'),
        data: (userProfile) => UserProfileForm(userProfile: userProfile),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For the life of me I'm not able to return the "User Profile" object to the user profile screen widget and I'm not really sure what is causing the issue. I'm fairly new to Flutter/Riverpod & Firebase so please forgive me if this seems like an obvious issue that I can't seem to rectify.

Here is what I'm seeing in the debug console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54248/peCvZyDPc10=/ws
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(32680): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10191; state: ENABLED
I/FirebaseApp(32680): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(32680): Compat change id reported: 3400644; UID 10191; state: DISABLED
D/FirebaseAuth(32680): Notifying id token listeners about user ( yEPCAfaHINVXuvEFohL6Tz5hdeN2 ).
D/EGL_emulation(32680): app_time_stats: avg=765.37ms min=4.54ms max=2249.99ms count=3
W/System  (32680): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/DynamiteModule(32680): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(32680): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(32680): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/TrafficStats(32680): tagSocket(141) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/nativeloader(32680): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(32680): Configuring clns-8 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(32680): Configuring clns-9 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/ApplicationLoaders(32680): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar
D/ApplicationLoaders(32680): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.sidecar.jar
D/nativeloader(32680): Configuring clns-10 for other apk /data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~v9Tvc8iBiPaG_hmHurZGEQ==/com.google.android.gms-PSpsgYGYIjloAogbvfwMMQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
V/NativeCrypto(32680): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/m_connector_app(32680): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(32680): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/TrafficStats(32680): tagSocket(126) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/m_connector_app(32680): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/m_connector_app(32680): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/System  (32680): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats(32680): tagSocket(152) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/FirebaseAuth(32680): Notifying id token listeners about user ( yEPCAfaHINVXuvEFohL6Tz5hdeN2 ).
D/EGL_emulation(32680): app_time_stats: avg=19.69ms min=9.10ms max=116.23ms count=51
```

Here is the stack trace based on the latest updates to the code:

```
#0      new UserProfile.fromMap (package:rpm_connector_app/src/features/user_profile/domain/user_profile.dart:26:39)
#1      UserProfileRepository.watchUser.<anonymous closure> (package:rpm_connector_app/src/features/user_profile/data/user_profile_repository.dart:19:27)
#2      _WithConverterDocumentSnapshot.data (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:119:26)
#3      UserProfileRepository.watchUser.<anonymous closure> (package:rpm_connector_app/src/features/user_profile/data/user_profile_repository.dart:22:35)
#4      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
#5      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#6      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#9      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#10     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
#11     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#12     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#16     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
#17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#18     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#19     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#20     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
#21     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
#22     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
#23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `firebaseAuthProvider`?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: 

`final firebaseAuthProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance;
});`

Comment: _I'm not able to return the "User Profile" object to the user profile screen_ can you elaborate on what did you expect and what you get?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to retrieve a document from Firestore that has the user's details such as name, date of birth, phone number, etc. The document is retrieved and converted into a `UserProfile` object by the `watchJob` function within the `UserProfileRepository` class using a `fromMap` function that's defined within the `UserProfile` class. 

The document definitely exists in Firestore, and I was able to successfully retrieve it when calling from the widget class, but for some reason I'm getting a null value when trying to retrieve the document using a stream.

Comment: After making some changes to the app, I'm now seeing an error of "Type 'null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast" which is occurring when trying to build the `UserProfile` object after making the call to retrieve the document from Firestore. I'm assuming this is happening because no document was retrieved from Firestore, which doesn't make sense because the document definitely exists. I've tried putting the direct path to the document instead of `userProfilePath(uid)` in `Stream<UserProfile> watchUser(String uid) => _fireStore
      .doc(userProfilePath(uid))` and same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Riverpod, you can use [`StreamProvider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider) instead of regular [`Provider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/provider) to expose the `UserProfile` stream.

```dart
final userProfileStreamProvider = StreamProvider<UserProfile>((ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    throw AssertionError('User can\'t be null.');
  }
  final repository = ref.watch(userProfileRepositoryProvider);
  return repository.watchUser(user.uid);
});
```

And then in the `build` method of your widget you can replace the `StreamBuilder` with the `when` method of Riverpod's [`AsyncValue`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValue-class.html) like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final userProfile = ref.watch(userProfileStreamProvider);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Profile'),
    ),
    body: userProfile.when(
      loading: () => Text('Widget to show when loading'),
      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Widget to show on error'),
      data: (userProfile) => Form(...),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dhafin. I have updated the code based on your recommendations, but I'm still coming across the same error: "Type 'null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast". I have edited the post to include the stack trace based on the code changes you recommended.